# How can I control an Irobot Create using Jetson Nano?

Tags: irobot-create

I have an irobot create 4400 model and I'm trying to use a jetson nano to send commands to it. I want to try [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p20qs.jpg) that turns on the play led. I connected the tx and rx and gnd ports from J41 header on the jetson nano to rx and tx and gnd ports on create's db25. Here's [my code](https://ideone.com/ZghN0y).

However, the create just won't move at all. I don't know if I'm missing some setup steps or just simply my codes are wrong. I wonder if anyone could be kind enough to check and see if there's anything wrong with my code? How would u write it if u want to send this command? Sorry if my problem is a bit foolish, but I'm really new to this and everything seems so complicated.

Comment: Hi me7ogo 7, can you provide some more details on your setup?  For example a more detailed electrical diagram with pin numbers.  Also, are you trying to communicate with the green "command module" or the Roomba itself?

Comment: Error says '/dev/ttyTHS1' cannot be found.  If you list serial ports `ls /dev/tty*` does it appear in the list?  Double check your wiring; make sure TX->RX and RX->TX, and you are using the correct pins.

Answer (score 0):

Try this API note this is a python API.
https://pypi.org/project/pycreate2/

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* GBB. Thanks for your answer but we prefer answers to be self contained where possible. Links [tend to rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) so answers which rely on a link can be rendered useless if the linked content disappears. If you add more context from the link, it is more likely that people will find your answer useful. See [answer] for more info.